# IOS - Concatenate multiple strings & vars

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm struggling with what I imagine is fairly simple - but I need to create a string by joining various strings and string vars together - this is what i have so far -

```
 _msgTxt = @"I have achieved great results with my instructor%@", _usrName,  @"Check her out here", _usrURL;
```

any tips on where i'm going wrong?  I'm hoping to achieve a long string ie ' I have achieved great results with my instructor Zoe Edwards.  Check her out here http://www.nme.com" which could be posted to social media channels.

Cheers

Comment: You haven't said what's not working. (I think I can tell, but it's helpful if you say what output you're looking for and what you're getting instead.)

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `stringWithFormat`.

Example:

```
_msgTxt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I have achieved great results with my instructor %@. Check her out here %@", _usrName, _usrURL];
```

One thing to keep in mind using the example above is that the objects/variables provided should appropriately use the `description` method to output user visible strings. `NSString` does, but other objects may output something which isn't user friendly.

If this is the case, you should use an NSString object within the parent object to display the information (You'd need to create this yourself; `_usrURL.userFriendlyString` for example).

Comment: sweet - will give it a try - nice one..

Answer (score 0):

Use `[NSString stringWithFormat:*enter you stuff here*];`

Answer (score 0):

While `stringWithFormat:` will work as proposed by the other answers, it isn't very efficient if you just want to concatenate a number of strings in a set order. The power of `stringWithFormat:` comes from the contents of the format and the ability to reorganise and 'format' contents with the parameter specifiers. But it comes with a cost because the format string has to be parsed and processed.

For simple string concatenation, use `NSMutableString` and the `appendString:` method. (and note that you can also use `appendFormat:` of you have one part that needs it...).

Comment: I'd be interested to see how different they are in terms of performance. Do you have any references for `stringWithFormat:` being inefficient in this case?

Comment: I don't have a reference for the performance comparison. You won't notice if you are just doing one concatenation every now and again. But your code should be more easily understandable and your users will like your use of the battery if you're more efficient...

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your answer, after running some rudimentary tests. CPU usage is higher on average when dealing with multiple messages being sent to the `NSMutableString` instance, as the LOC for this operation is x4 instead of using `stringWithFormat:`. This overhead adds up, and starts to outweigh the benefits. I also found it slightly less readable due to the multiple statements required. Granted we don't know how `stringWithFormat` is optimised, but the typical use case is with a statically allocated format string, which could be optimised to only require a single pass parse.

Comment: @Wain: Unless all your app does is concatenate strings (at max CPU utilization, for minutes on end) you won't see this distinction anywhere meaningful, especially in battery life. Certainly in some cases, simple appending to a mutable string is the more straightforward approach, but this note is more appropriate as a comment on the question or on the accepted answer.